# SQLite time duration calculation from rows

Tags: sqlite

I want to calculate duration between rows with datetime data in SQLite.

Let's consider this for the base data (named *intervals*):

```
| id |       date       |  state  |
|  1 | 2020-07-04 10:11 | On      |
|  2 | 2020-07-04 10:22 | Off     |
|  3 | 2020-07-04 11:10 | On      |
|  4 | 2020-07-04 11:25 | Off     |
```

I'd like to calculate the duration for both `On` and `Off` state:

```
| Total On  | 26mins |
| Total Off | 48mins |
```

Then I wrote this query:

```
SELECT
  "Total " || interval_start.state AS state,
  (SUM(strftime('%s', interval_end.date)-strftime('%s', interval_start.date)) / 60) || "mins" AS duration
FROM
  intervals interval_start
INNER JOIN
  intervals interval_end ON interval_end.id = 
    (
      SELECT id FROM intervals WHERE
        id > interval_start.id AND
        state = CASE WHEN interval_start.state = 'On' THEN 'Off' ELSE 'On' END
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 1
    )
GROUP BY
  interval_start.state
```

However if the base data is a not in strict order:

```
| id |       date       |  state  |
|  1 | 2020-07-04 10:11 | On      |
|  2 | 2020-07-04 10:22 | On      | !!!
|  3 | 2020-07-04 11:10 | On      |
|  4 | 2020-07-04 11:25 | Off     |
```

My query will calculate wrong, as it will pair the only `Off` date with each `On` dates and sum them together.

Desired behavior should result something like this:

```
| Total On  | 74mins |
| Total Off | 0mins  | --this line can be omitted, or can be N/A
```

**I have two questions:**

1. How can I rewrite the query to handle these wrong data situations?
2. I feel my query is not the best in terms of performance, is it possible to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE where you return only the starting rows of each state and then aggregate:

```
with cte as (
  select *, lead(id) over (order by date) next_id
  from (
    select *, lag(state) over (order by date) prev_state
    from intervals
  )
  where state <> coalesce(prev_state, '')
) 
select c1.state,
  sum(strftime('%s', c2.date) - strftime('%s', c1.date)) / 60 || 'mins' duration
from cte c1 inner join cte c2
on c2.id = c1.next_id
group by c1.state
```

See the demos: [1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eY7DfJcXk17hDPLToHveiZ/3) and [2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5zfyquviGnxzrwKJtL9crx/2)

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how efficient is this? Or how can I make it more efficient? There are 1 query with a subquery and this is joined to itself, plus there is another query. If I drop 10k rows in, DBFiddle needs more than 200ms to calculate.

Comment: Window functions is the best choice when there is a large amount of data. But 10K rows is not a large amount of data. Try the code in another environment and not DBFiddle.