# SQlite view of durations from table of timestamps

Tags: sqlite, view, timestamp, duration, sql-view

I have a SQlite3 table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS automationProcessLog (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp text NOT NULL,    -- expected format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ssssss+ZZ:ZZ
    month_day text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(timestamp, 6, 2) || '-' || substr(timestamp, 9, 2)) STORED,      -- expected format MM-dd
    hour integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(timestamp, 12, 2)) STORED,
    minute integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(timestamp, 15, 2)) STORED,
    weekday text NOT NULL,
    sampleID text,
    carrierID text,
    nodeID text,
    IOnode text,    -- expected True/False
    nodeType string GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(nodeID, 1, instr(nodeID, '/')-1)) STORED,
    nodeNumberByType integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(nodeID, instr(nodeID, '/')+1, length(nodeID))) STORED,
    processStep text,
    data text,
    FOREIGN KEY(nodeID) REFERENCES nodes(nodeID)
)
```

This table contains all events for samples (`sampleID`) transported by carriers (`carrierID`) between nodes (`nodeID`) on an automation. A carrier can only carry one sample at a time.

I would like to create a view where I have `sampleID`, `carrierID`, `timestamp` when the sample was introduced to the automation, `nodeID` where the sample was introduced, `timestamp` when the sample was handled (i.e. anything but loaded), `nodeID` where the sample was handled, and the `duration` from load to handled.

- A sample is loaded when the row has `IOnode = "True"` and `processStep = "Processed"`
- A sample can be processed at several nodes, and sometimes even repeatedly at the same node, before arriving at the final destination. In such cases `duration` is still counted from when the sample was loaded onto the automation.
- A sample can get re-introduced to the automation after being unloaded. `duration` is to be counted from the last loading of the sample.

Some pseudo-logic would be to select `sampleID`, `carrierID`, `timestamp` (`timestamp_processed`), and `nodeID` (`nodeID_processed`) `WHERE NOT (IOnode = "True" AND processStep = "Processed")`, to this add `timestamp` (`timestamp_loaded`) and `nodeID` (`nodeID_loaded`) for the row with the same `sampleID` and `carrierID` with the latest (greatest) `timestamp` that is earlier (less) than `timestamp_processed` `WHERE (IOnode = "True" AND processStep = "Processed")`, and to this calculate the `duration` between the timestamps.

I have been looking at the `LAG` function as well as answers to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737742/sqlite-time-duration-calculation-from-rows), but I have not been able to produce something that works.

Comment: Your requirement could be better clarified with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_) (covering any edge cases) and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery or CTE to extract loading times, using the `lead()` window function to also get the next load time for the same sample.

Then join it with the main table to get the corresponding processing steps and durations.

```
WITH load_times AS (
    SELECT sampleID, timestamp as timestamp_loaded, nodeID as nodeID_loaded, 
           lead(timestamp,1,'2999-12-31') OVER (PARTITION BY sampleID ORDER BY timestamp) as next_load
    FROM automationProcessLog 
    WHERE IOnode = 'True' and processStep = 'Processed'
)
SELECT sampleID, carrierID, timestamp as timestamp_processed, nodeID as nodeID_processed, 
       timestamp_loaded, nodeID_loaded, 
       (unixepoch(timestamp_processed) - unixepoch(timestamp_loaded)) as duration
FROM automationProcessLog l 
JOIN load_times lt ON (l.sampleID = lt.sampleID AND l.timestamp BETWEEN lt.timestamp_loaded AND lt.next_load)
WHERE NOT (l.IOnode = 'True' and l.processStep = 'Processed')
```

Comment: Unfortunately the database is in the next step going to be read by an SQlite ODBC driver which, as it turns out, doesn't support unixepoch, but by just leving that part out I still have both times in the view and can make that calculation in the software using the database.